# Will be next SharePoint 13/15 have new deploy features?

Tags: deployment, solution-deployment, gac, public-website, 2013

Over the past couple of years I've been making solutions for SharePoint Server and always most important problem was the availability of the web-site. Deployment not-sandboxed solution is pain at least for 30 seconds for each wsp. This operation requires recycle of Application Pool (include the farm one) and in fact this means *503 Service Unavailable* http response from IIS Server.

We usaully use SharePoint for external Internet web sites and we expect the highest possible percentage of availability. (Two farm for replication, powershell-automation, read-only mode while deploying, etc.)

Yesterday Microsoft released SharePoint 13 Preview. I've just downloaded slides[1](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/7/3/773CA2C2-579B-408C-808E-A6F561194E20/Ig15_SP_IT_M05V2_deploy.pptx) and see there

> Never any reason to have separate farms (Except security)

Any possibility for another deploy scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the statement is more related to Office Web Apps capabilities rather than overall SharePoint farm or deployed solutions. In your case, probably you should consider using more Sandboxed solutions, or re-architect farm solutions to include part of these as sandboxed solutions, because the trend set out for the future is cloud compatibility, etc., which starts with you not really having the possibility to deploy farm solutions.

The reason why SP2013 now has a "Store" built-in which deploys sandboxed solutions only.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks. Alse, for difficult application we start using ASP.NET MVC integrated through SharePoint REST API and Custom Web Services.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 the general direction is away from any code on the server. They've enhanced client site object mode/REST as well as created the new posibility for Apps where you run the code outside SharePoint, but get permissions though OAuth tokens

Comment: In most cases it is safer and easier. Now I understand.

Comment: Related: [Introducing Napa](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/07/17/introducing-napa-office-365-development-tools.aspx)